# gcloud builds submit hangs

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-build

When I try to run the example in https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/quickstarts/build-and-deploy, my terminal hangs on `gcloud builds submit --tag gcr.io/PROJECT-ID/helloworld`. I put in my correct project id -- the command runs but does not terminate or produce any output on terminal. I did not change any code, I merely copied over the repo referenced in the tutorial. What may be the cause of this?

Comment: which version of the SDK are you using? to know this you can run: `gcloud version` have you tried to do this from cloud shell?

Answer (score 3):

I solved it. I tried using gsutil and it would also hang. I ended up disabling ipv6 by using `sudo sysctl -w net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6=1` and `sudo sysctl -w net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6=1`.

Comment: Does your ISP have a problem with IPv6?

Answer (score 0):

Can be caused by many things.

To debug, use:

```
gcloud builds submit --config ./cloudbuild.yaml --verbosity=debug
```